# Need to calculate running balance of debit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am working for 1 accounts project and i have stuck in 1 place.

Table is debit

```
ID      Debit       Credit      A       B       C   
1       1000.00     900.00      0       0       1000.00     
2       450.00      425.00      0       450.00  0   
3       500.00      490.00      500.00  0       0   
4       600.00      599.00      600.00  0       0   
5       748.00      700.00      0       748.00  0   


Now if we sum the credit it will be = 3114,  
What I have to do here is whatever total credit I have it has to start from top (A+B+C) - 3114  
So It will make C = 0 and my new credit will be 3114-1000=2114,   
Then in my id=2 it will do the same thing (A+B+C) - 2114  
so now B will be 0 and my new credit will be 2114-450=1664
```

My end output after all the calculation it should be

```
ID      Debit       Credit      A       B       C   
1       1000.00     900.00      0       0       0.00        
2       450.00      425.00      0       0.00    0   
3       500.00      490.00      0.00    0       0   
4       600.00      599.00      0.00    0       0   
5       748.00      700.00      0       184.00  0
```

If we try to (sum A + Sum B + Sum C) - credit, figure will be the same but it will come in column A, So after all the brainstorming I think above calculation has to be applied.

Do anyone has any idea how to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't follow your logic for computing a running total here.

Comment: which logic you didn't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server only support analytics function `SUM() OVER` from version MSSQL 2012, so for 2008 this may be one way to query your result:

```
WITH table_name AS
( 
    SELECT 1 ID, 000.00 Debit, 900.00 Credit, 0       a, 0       b, 1000.00     c UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 ID, 450.00 Debit, 425.00 Credit, 0       a, 450.00  b, 0   c UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 ID, 500.00 Debit, 490.00 Credit, 500.00  a, 0       b, 0   c UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 ID, 600.00 Debit, 599.00 Credit, 600.00  a, 0       b, 0   c UNION ALL
    SELECT 5 ID, 748.00 Debit, 700.00 Credit, 0       a, 748.00  b, 0   c 
)
, 
sum_credit AS
(
    SELECT SUM(credit) sumcredit 
    FROM table_name
)
SELECT t.id, t.debit, t.credit, 
    CASE WHEN a = 0
            OR ( (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
                + a - sc.sumcredit < 0
            )
        THEN 0 
        ELSE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
            + a - sc.sumcredit 
        END a,
    CASE WHEN b = 0
            OR ( (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
                + a + b - sc.sumcredit < 0
            )
        THEN 0 
        ELSE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
            + a + b - sc.sumcredit 
        END b,
    CASE WHEN c = 0 
            OR ( (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
                + a + b + c - sc.sumcredit < 0
            )
        THEN 0 
        ELSE (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(a + b + c), 0) FROM table_name WHERE id < t.id)
            + a + b + c - sc.sumcredit 
        END c
FROM 
    table_name t
CROSS JOIN 
    sum_credit sc;
```

Comment: Hi Pham I tried your query in my actual code,                                        15 2606.67 0.00 0.00  0.00   
16 1955.00 0.00 0.00 1835.43   
17 45.62 0.00 0.00 1881.05   
18 26.07 0.00 0.00 1907.12   
19 312.80 0.00 0.00 2219.92   
20 24196.50 0.00 0.00 26416.42            26416.42 is the correct output what I wanted, but all output before that why it is not turning to 0

Comment: @RedDevil can you give some example, i.e which output that's not turning to 0 (e.g 14 credit_val x 0 0)? And as the query is quite clear, could you find out why (negative value, id's not less than.....)?